# Where Clause Woes in Stored MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, where-clause

What I'd like to do is execute a MySQL query containing a `where` clause ("result query") that is stored in a column in the database. This column, containing the query, is a result of another query ("original query").

**The catches:**

- The result query's where clause can contain a variable value (or two)
- I don't know what the result query will be when executing the original query, so I cannot pass along the variable's value

(The list of result queries as well as the variables in the `where` clauses will be defined by me, so I will will have a list of all the possible variables.)

Essentially, I need to be able to correlate that variable with any number of other values, one example: a user_id, within the database.

```
original_query_table      | result_query_table
--------------------------------------------------------------
other_id result_query_id  | result_query_id  result_query
1        1                  1                "SELECT ... WHERE user_id = :id "
```

I know how to do this with two separate queries, but the question is whether this is possible with only one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
SELECT 'select * from table_a where col_a = ?' INTO @query, 1 into @param1 FROM dual;
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt USING @param1 ;
```

So converting that into your tables, I guess would look like:

```
SELECT a.result_query INTO @query, b.result_query_id INTO @param1 FROM result_query_table a, original_query_table b where a.result_query_id = b.result_query_id;
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt USING @param1 ;
```

Will you know how many parameters the where clause will need? If that's dynamic, then things could get a bit tricky.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is the issue. I don't know how many parameters it will need. Sometimes it's 1, sometimes it's 3. I'm not set on the table structure though, if changing that helps?

Comment: So this answer helped me on another issue I was having. You deserve the credit for it. Don't spend all the points in one place :P